# XML Parsing using Structures in C++

Tags: c++, function, scope

I have tried to parse an xml file using tinyxml API in C++ through structure implementation, but my below code does not produce the result which i am expected. Below is the My code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include<string>
#include"tinyxml.h"

using namespace std;

struct accsys
{
    string name;
    string type;
    float rate;
};

void parser(struct accsys acc)
{   
    list<accsys> l;
    TiXmlDocument* doc= new TiXmlDocument();
    doc->LoadFile("accountsys.xml");
    TiXmlElement* root=doc->RootElement(); 
    TiXmlElement* accountElement=root->FirstChildElement(); 
    while(accountElement)
    {
        TiXmlElement* nameElement=accountElement->FirstChildElement(); 
        acc.name=nameElement->GetText();
        TiXmlElement* typeElement=nameElement->NextSiblingElement(); 
        acc.type=typeElement->GetText();
        TiXmlElement* rateElement=typeElement->NextSiblingElement(); 
            acc.rate=atof(rateElement->GetText());
        l.push_back(acc);
        accountElement=accountElement->NextSiblingElement();
    }
}

void display(struct accsys acc)
{   
    list<accsys> l;
    list<accsys>::iterator i;
    i=l.begin();
    while(i!=l.end())
    {
        cout<<"name:"<<i->name<<endl;
        cout<<"type:"<<i->type<<endl;
        cout<<"rate:"<<i->rate<<endl;
        i++;
    }
}


int main()
{
    struct accsys acc;
    parser(acc);
    display(acc);
    return 0;
}
```

Can any one answer please!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What result do you expect? What result are you receiving? What is the XML file you're parsing? Thanks.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with parsing XML. You should read about variable scope in C++. You create empty lists in both your functions that are just discarded when the functions end ...

Comment: It is critical to ask a concrete question or people will down vote your question. In this case you need to answer the questions posed by @JoelC.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, pass a reference to the std::list, not a empty struct, which won't live longer than in the function you make it. Neither can you make a list in one function and expect it to be there in another.

Fixed formatting, removed this ugly `using namespace std;`, and corrected your code. I assume this is what you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include "tinyxml.h"


struct accsys
{
    std::string name;
    std::string type;
    float rate;
};

void parser(std::list<accsys> &acc)
{
    TiXmlDocument *doc = new TiXmlDocument();
    doc->LoadFile("accountsys.xml");
    TiXmlElement *root = doc->RootElement(); 
    TiXmlElement *accountElement = root->FirstChildElement(); 
    while (accountElement)
    {
        struct accsys structAcc;
        TiXmlElement *nameElement = accountElement->FirstChildElement(); 
        structAcc.name = nameElement->GetText();
        TiXmlElement *typeElement = nameElement->NextSiblingElement(); 
        structAcc.type = typeElement->GetText();
        TiXmlElement *rateElement = typeElement->NextSiblingElement(); 
        structAcc.rate = atof(rateElement->GetText());
        acc.push_back(structAcc);
        accountElement = accountElement->NextSiblingElement();
    }
}

void display(std::list<accsys> &acc)
{   
    for (std::list<accsys>::iterator itr = acc.begin(); itr != acc.end(); ++itr)
    {
        std::cout << "name: " << itr->name << std::endl;
        std::cout << "type: " << itr->type << std::endl;
        std::cout << "rate: " << itr->rate << std::endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::list<accsys> acc;
    parser(acc);
    display(acc);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see at least 3 big errors in your code:

1) As marcinj has alrteady pointed out you are passing to your parser() function a copy of the struct accsys and whatever you fill in that structure you will never find it outside the function.

2) Again in parser you declare a list of your accsys struct which is local to the function, whatever you put in the list you will never see it outside the function, moreover in the while loop you keep overwriting values in your acc struct so even in the best case you would only see the last line of you xml file.

3) In the display function you pass an accsys struct to the function and the you forget it and try to print the content of a list of struct just created which is obviously empty.

So supposing the xml parser is correct your code would have to be more or less like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include<string>
#include"tinyxml.h"

using namespace std;

struct accsys
{
    string name;
    string type;
    float rate;
};

void parser(list<struct accsys *> &accList)
{   
    TiXmlDocument* doc= new TiXmlDocument();
    doc->LoadFile("accountsys.xml");
    TiXmlElement* root=doc->RootElement(); 
    TiXmlElement* accountElement=root->FirstChildElement(); 
    while(accountElement)
    {
        struct accsys *acc = new struct accsys;
        TiXmlElement* nameElement=accountElement->FirstChildElement(); 
        acc->name=nameElement->GetText();
        TiXmlElement* typeElement=nameElement->NextSiblingElement(); 
        acc->type=typeElement->GetText();
        TiXmlElement* rateElement=typeElement->NextSiblingElement(); 
            acc->rate=atof(rateElement->GetText());
        l.push_back(acc);
        accountElement=accountElement->NextSiblingElement();
    }
}

void display(list<struct accsys *> &l)
{   
    list<struct accsys *>::iterator i;
    i=l.begin();
    while(i!=l.end())
    {
        cout<<"name:"<<i->name<<endl;
        cout<<"type:"<<i->type<<endl;
        cout<<"rate:"<<i->rate<<endl;
        i++;
    }
}


int main()
{
    list <struct accsys *> acc;
    parser(acc);
    display(acc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all valuable answers but I have a one doubt. Is structure members variable getting overwritten. If so kindly help how to avoid it from  being over written.

Comment: @Delhi What do you mean exactly ? The list will contain all your structures and in the structures are your members.

Comment: @Macro You have bad memory leaks there.

Comment: I need clarification on whether the struct variable is overwritting for each while loop iteration or not.

Comment: If you look at the code I have suggested you, there is this line:

struct accsys *acc = new struct accsys;

This way the acc becomes a pointer and then new memory is allocated to hold each of the strings you need to print, this way you will not overwrite your struct on every loop, blacktempel is right there is a risk of memory leak in there so if this is a pieace of a big application you will have to deal with it.

Comment: Thanks Macro. I will handle the memory leak. Once again thanks to you all.

Comment: @Marco There is not a just a risk of a memory leak. Each of your allocated `struct accsys *acc = new struct accsys;` IS a memory leak in your code, as you do not delete them anywhere. Basically you just just suggested to allocate memory and have a memory leak INSTEAD of just using a local (system allocated and freed) `struct accsys structAcc;`. When you pass it to the list, a copy of it will be made in the list. `this way you will not overwrite your struct on every loop` this does not make sense. If you re-enter the loop, there is the same variable-name, but not the same memory location. Bad ^

Comment: @Delhi You do not need to handle any memory leaks, simply do not use a pointer and do not allocate. This is really not needed here.